# How to transfer audio data continuously to the server in iOS by Http Post Chunked?

Tags: ios, audio, stream, chunked

Recently , I am working on a rare iOS task. I am going to transfer the audio data to the server when recording . The server only accept http post chunked request. And the params of request should be set in the http request header. Has anyone ever done such a thing before ?

Comment: As is, this comment is too broad.  Please make it more specific.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I'm going to use iOS Audio Unit and Libcurl to solve this issue. But still a bit of a problem in sending audio data to the server continuously . The request result return immediately when the first chunked data sent .

Comment: Can you provide specific technical details, for instance what your current code looks like, and what the data is you get returned?  Please put this **in your question**, not in a comment.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Finally I make it. Audio Queue produces audio data buffer. And 
I implement http protocol based on socket to send audio data buffer.  Thanks for your reply !